# Problem with defining the range of $f(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$

Tags: inequality

> Find the $D_f$ of $f(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$

**Personal work:**
We have to solve the inequality: $x+\sqrt{x^2+1}>0$

I've thought of raising both sides powers' to $^2$ so the root can go away. So, we have: $$x^2+x^2+1>0 \iff 2x^2+1>0$$ And it's always positive. Problem? I need to find the $D_f$ of $f(x).$

Comment: $(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})^2=x^2+2x\sqrt{x^2+1}+x^2+1\neq x^2+x^2+1$

Comment: Does $D_f$ mean the range (your title)? Or is it the domain?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen the range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your title you are asking for the range of $f(x)$, however it *seems* you are attempting to solve for the *domain* of $f(x)$, so I will provide such a solution. If it is not the case, please clarify.

The logarithm function is defined for $x>0$, so we want to solve the inequality $x+\sqrt{x^2+1}> 0$. This is equivalent to solving  \begin{align}\sqrt{x^2+1}> -x \tag{1} \end{align} and we have to consider two cases: when $x$ is positive and when $x$ is negative. So

- Case $x > 0: $ notice the right hand side of $(1)$ becomes negative, and the left hand side is positive, since $x^2+1$  is always positive. Hence it is true for all $x>0$.
- Case $x\leq0: $ Then we have that both the RHS and LHS are non-negative, so we have that
  \begin{align}\sqrt{x^2+1}> -x \iff\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)^2> (-x)^2 \iff x^2+1>x^2 \iff1>0,\end{align}
  which is true for all $x$.

Hence the domain of $f(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$ is all the real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

No issues if $x\geq 0$. If $x<0$ then $\sqrt{x^2+1}+x$ is positive anyway, since $\sqrt{x^2+1}>|x|$, hence $f(x)=\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$ is defined for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. We may also notice that
$$ f(\sinh u) = \log(\sinh u+\cosh u) = \log(e^u) = u $$
hence $f(x)=\text{arcsinh}(x)$ is the inverse function of $\sinh$, which is bijective over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Therefore the Range of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb R$ since for both $x>0$ and $x<0, f(x)$ is always positive?

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis: $f(x)$ is not always positive, but the (maximal) domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$ (since $x+\sqrt{1+x^2}$ is positive) and the (maximal) domain of $f^{-1}$ is also $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis: on the other hand, assuming $f(x)>0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the range of $f$ **cannot** be the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: TLDR: since $\sinh$ is bijective over $\mathbb{R}$, $\log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$ is also bijective over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $\sqrt{x^2+1}>\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, so the **domain** (against the title, as suggest notation and your attempt) is...

(Your method assumes nonnegative $x$).

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $x=\cot2y$ where $0<2y\le\pi$

$$x+\sqrt{x^2+1}=\cot2y+\csc2y=\cot y$$ for $1+\cos2y\ne0\iff2y\ne\pi$

$0<\cot y<\infty$

Comment: Are you sure an answer like this is actually helpful for someone with the level of the asker? Or is your post meant for other Math SE users?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, I think any user with basic trigonometry knowledge should understand the post.